# OneDrive Search API always returns the result from the root

Tags: onedrive, live-sdk

When I try to search something from a SPECIFIC folder:

```
https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/items/{the_folder_id}/view.search?q=txt
```

the API always returns the search result from the ROOT folder. I tried using the API console, and the problem is still the same.
Is this a OneDrive bug ?

Comment: I've created https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/257 for you

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with the service, and not an issue with how you're using it. We're working on resolving it now - you can use [this link](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/257) to track our progress.

Thanks for letting us know!